# Which faiths are accepted for membership in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, lutheranism

My husband and I were married in a Lutheran Church. He is Episcopal, I was Lutheran, then Confirmed Episcopal, but am now Confirmed Catholic for 26 years.

The Monsignor at our previous parish said the

> Lutheran Church was one of the Churches

that was accepted for marriage—we have been married 46 years!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but it seems like the obvious answer is ' The Catholic faith is the only faith accepted for membership in the Catholic Church.' Anyone intent on joining would be expected to conform to the Catholic faith no matter which (possibly non-Christian) tradition they come from.

Comment: Hi Sandra - I'm not sure what you're asking about. Are you asking whether the Catholic Church still considers you married? (Congratulations by the way on 46 years of marriage; that's an awesome achievement!)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  Is your question whether or not the church holds your marriage to be valid?  Did you ask your  Monsignor that question? (Since Canon Law holds that marriage is a sacrament between the baptized, and you were both baptized by church's whose baptism is reconginzed by the catholic church, that may be what your Monsignor was referring to.  Is there a problem that needs solving?

Answer (score 1):

A candidate for membership in the Catholic church will go through the RCIA (Rite of Catholic Initiation for Adults) course as you did. This is the ordinary method for anyone to enter the church. Assuming your husband was not previously married and divorced, *unless his earlier wife is still alive*, there is not any impediment to your husband joining the Catholic church. Check with your Parish Priest for a more complete answer.

Comment: I think there's some syntax error on the "previously married and divorce" line, I think I fixed it - I'm guessing there's probably a few more impediments to becoming a member of the Catholic Church than divorce.  (And, I'm kind of wondering if after 46 years of marriage a married and divorced couple could legitimately pledge to live as brother and sister for the rest of their lives and not incite some sort of scandal)

Comment: I understand that if the husband had been married and divorced, and his first wife was still alive, there might be the need for a determination as to the sacramental state of the  first marriage by the marriage tribunal. If  the first  wife was dead, or there was no first wife, there is no impediment that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Given the facts of your question. If you could become a member (no additional Baptism, just the sacrament of Confirmation), then he should be able to become a member.  This is pretty much the same (although the time scale is a bit wider and the sexes reversed) situation that G.K. Chesterton and his wife Frances went through, so you're in good company.

Here is what the United States Bishops Conference saiys about coming in to the Church from other Christian denominations.

> **What is meant when by coming into full communion with the Church?**
>
> Coming into full communion with the Catholic Church describes the process for entrance into the Catholic Church for already baptized Christians. In most cases, these individuals make a profession of faith but are not baptized again. To prepare for this reception, the people, who are called Candidates, usually participate in a formation program to help them understand and experience the teachings and practices of the Catholic Church. Although some preparation may be with Catechumens preparing for baptism, the preparation for Candidates is different since they have already been baptized and committed to Jesus Christ, and many have also been active members of other Christian communities. The Candidates may be received into the Catholic Church at the Easter Vigil or at another Sunday during the year depending on pastoral circumstances and readiness of the Candidate.
>
> [USCCB Website - RCIA](http://www.usccb.org/beliefs-and-teachings/who-we-teach/rite-of-christian-initiation-of-adults/index.cfm)

---

To your second point, I think your old pastor would have a hard time naming the denominations whose marriage they would not recognize, but its easy to name ones they do. For instance, I think it's just easier for someone to say, "Lutheran... yep, that's a good one" than to have to look in to the traditions and practices of the Second Oak Park Brook Creekside Church of Tuscaloosa.